# mySQL Data loading: Better to column map or INSERT SELECT INTO ETL?

Tags: mysql, import

I've got 125 csv files to upload into a database. The files are typically ~200K rows and 30 columns.

In order to make the data more relational I was going to column map during LOAD DATA INFILE process (specific columns into specific tables) via bash script. But now I'm wondering if it makes more sense to LOAD all the files and use INSERT SELECT INTO to do my ETL'ing.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have CSV files, it makes a lot more sense to use `LOAD DATA`.  Put them into 125 tables.  After that, you can do the massaging that you suggest doing with bash.